# Setup statsd-exporter as daemon on Kubernetes and send metrics to it from pods

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, statsd

I want to setup `statsd-exporter` as DaemonSet on my Kubernetes cluster. It exposes a UDP port 9125, on which applications can send metrics using statsD client library. `Prometheus` crawlers can crawl this exporter for application or system metrics. I want to send the metrics to the UDP server running in the exporter on port 9125. I have two options:

1. Expose a service as `ClusterIP` for the DaemonSet and then configure the statsD clients to use that IP and Port for sending metrics
2. Make the `statsd-exporter` run on `hostNetwork`, and somehow enable the pods to send metrics to `exporter` running on the same node.

Somehow, option 2 seems better, since my pods will be sending metrics to an exporter running on the same node, but I am not able to send metrics to the local pod of `statsd-exporter` since I don't have the IP of the node the pod is running on.

Can you please compare the pros and cons of both methods, and suggest how can I know the IP address of Node on which the pod is running along with the exporter.

**EDIT 1**

I am able to get the Node IP by adding the environment variable.

```
- name: NODE_IP
  valueFrom:
    fieldRef:
      fieldPath: status.hostIP
```

I still need clarity on which will be better approach to setting this up. Exposing a service with type `ClusterIP` and then using the `HOST:PORT` from environment variable in the pod or use `hostNetwork: true` in pod spec and then access it using `NODE_IP` environment variable. Does clusterIp guarantees that the packet will be routed to the same node as the pod sending the packet?

**EDIT 2**

I explored [headless service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#headless-services) and I think this comes closest to what I want. But I am not sure that the DNS resolution will return the local node IP as the first result in `nslookup`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest one of the below two approaches, both have their pros and cons.

- Fast, may not be entirely secure.

Daemon set using `hostPort`. It would be fast as both pods would be on the same node, but the statsd port would be exposed. (You need to secure statsd by some other way)

- Not as fast as `hostPort` but secure

Exposing a service and using the service dns to connect (`servicename.namespace.svc.cluster.local`). Not as fast as the `hostPort` as there is no way to reach specific pod, but secure as no one from outside the cluster can hit the statsd.

More details: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/daemonset/#communicating-with-daemon-pods

Comment: Yeah, I also feel that those are the way to go. I will wait for a while for other opinions to come in.